# Weather RSS feed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, rss, weather

I've got a task to build a digital display which includes Outside temperature eg 27C, Today's weather Sunny with a sun image 17C to 25C and tomorrow's weather.

I'm new to this RSS field, so any help would be appreciated! I've been searching this afternoon, there are some weather widgets available but I couldn't figure out a way to alter the structure of many available ones.

Is there any good available links, code or tutorials that I can check out? Or any suggestion or direction would be helpful.

Is there any way I can alter weather RSS feed eg from yahoo? How do I let the weather info display onto my site? Sorry being a bit lost and thank you for your time.

Kind regards
S:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321763/yahoo-weather-yahoo-geoplant-google-weather-or-another-api-to-connect-to-with-j

Comment: Consider using NWS data:  http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/  Fewer licensing restrictions, and it is regularly updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an rss parser like magpie and read off an rss feed such as:

www.rssweather.com/

http://www.weather.com/weather/rss/subscription

http://rss.weatherbug.com/

Magpie is here:

http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi John, thanks very much for your reply. I'm a bit lost as this is my first time doing RSS feed. I had a look at Magpie, but couldn't understand it very well. How are those weather rss websites related to the site I'm working on? I'm trying to figure out the relationship between all the codes. Sorry being lost here. Any of your help would be appreciated. Also how do I alter the format of the available RSS weather feed? Thanks heaps. S:)

Comment: Well it depends on what your going to use to display the weather information, php/jquery/javascript. I gave a php solution. RSS holds the information you are looking for, magpie is a way to read the rss feed and put the information from the rss feed into variables so you can display them in anyway you like on your side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RSS or weather RSS and program a custom object.  But we used a FeedSyndicate php feed to do exactly this for a client display  I could control text, image type and sizes....

Comment: Thank you Bill. I've used an weather add-on from simplepie, and its working now. thanks very much for your reply anyhow. Cheers, S